# Storing Multiple Data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to think of a way that a user can add a type(medical) on the frontend but a verifier has to approve that record? i can't seem to figure out the best solution for this, does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work? It's getting stored in the medical table but not in Verifier table.
In Simple words, I am using the *medicalRecord* Controller to stored medical and Verifier details. 
'document_id' = the medical_id; 
'submitted_by' = who created the record

```
  public function store Request $request, $id)
{


    if (auth_user_cannot(Capability::CREATE_DRIVER_MEDICAL_RECORD)) {
        return redirect($group['name'] . "/" . $group['userId']);
    }

    $all = $request->all();


    if ($request->hasFile('myfile')) {
        $result = upload($request->file('myfile'), 'nonzip', 'Medical');
        $all['upload'] = $result['upload'];
        $all['uploadId'] = $result['uploadId'];
    }

    // u'll need to save the medical to the user first, then save the verifier to the medical.

    $driverMedical = DriverMedicalRecord::create($all);

   // Then for the relation;
    $medical  =  $driverMedical->find($id);
    $verificationData = DocumentVerification::create( [
        'document_id' => $medical,
        'submitted_by'=> Auth::id(),
    ]) ;

    $request->user()->posts()->save($post);

    $driverMedical->verifier()->save($verificationData);
```

Comment: What type of relationship is verifier?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a flag in the same table and change its value when it got verified.
ex: `is_verfied` it should be 0 when it is not approved when it got approved change it to 1 (this is what i understand from your question)

Comment: thanks...I have added the Enum for the status to be rejected and is_verified. its working now...I think it wasn't working becoz there was no value in the status

Comment: @aneeqa chowdhury glad to help